# rigidbody.AddForce affects all game objects with the same script component

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

on scene I have 3 balls with Ball.cs script attached to each of them. And when I push ball with mouse all balls start moving, but I need that only one that I touch moves.

Here is my FixedUpdate:

```
void FixedUpdate() {
    if(!isMoving) {

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {

            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100)) {
                if(hit.collider.tag == "Ball") {
                    startPos = hit.point;
                }
            }
        }

        if (startPos != Vector3.zero && Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) {
            endPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

            Vector3 direction = endPos - startPos;
            direction.Normalize();

            float distance = Vector3.Distance(endPos, startPos);

            rigidbody.AddForce(direction * distance * force * Time.deltaTime, ForceMode.Impulse);

            isMoving = true;
        }
    } else {
        if(rigidbody.velocity.sqrMagnitude == 0) {
            isMoving = false;
            startPos = endPos = Vector3.zero;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't compare collider tags. Compare the collider to this instance's collider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [Nick Udell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24285635/rigidbody-addforce-affects-all-game-objects-with-the-same-script-component#comment37525457_24285635) already mentioned, your comparison of the tag is the source of your problem. All three balls are executing the same script at nearly the same time. So if you click on of the balls, all three scripts will cast a ray **at your mouse position** and check if they hit a ball. Guess what? All of them hit a ball but not the ball they belong to.

You need to check if they are hitting the collider attached to their GameObject

```
if (hit.collider == collider) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thank you guys. Now it works as I want, but I realized that more complicated code becomes harder to manage it. I think I will need some Game Manager